# How can identify the time consuming part of my code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, openai-gym

I'm training a model that learns how to upswing and hold a pendulum on a cart. I let it train in Google Colab while using their TPU's for faster processing times. But it still takes up to 5 seconds for one Episode. I think that the environment itself takes ages to compute. I took the `cartpolev0` from OpenAi's gym and changed it for my needs.

Is it possible to find the part of the program which is the heaviest to compute?

I think my environment is not running in multiprocessing.

Comment: You need to profile your code to know where it spend the most of the time. You can try using [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) for python

Comment: Is there a version for Python 3.8.5? In the description, just Python 2 is noted.